# @Url.Action pass id segment of current url

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing app in the dotnet core 3.1 C# MVC.

I have URL mapping in the Startup.cs file like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Have one controller named Dashboard and action method Index for which I have the URL like this.

```
<domain>/<controller>/<action>/<id>
http://localhost:57088/Dashboard/Index/03359edbae9543b5a1bc956e9282cfb6
```

In Razor pages whenever I create the link using the @Url.Action to the same controller and same action, it automatically add the id segment of the URL.

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard");
```

then it create the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:57088/Dashboard/Index/03359edbae9543b5a1bc956e9282cfb6
```

But when I create the URL using @Url.Action to different controller than it does not add the id segment of the URL.

```
@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Photos");
```

then it create the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:57088/Photos/DoSomething
```

but How can I create the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:57088/Photos/DoSomething/03359edbae9543b5a1bc956e9282cfb6
```

How can I add the same id segment to different controller as using the @Url.Action ?

Comment: Pass the appropriate route values to Url.Action

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Can you please provide the code example ?

Comment: Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard", new { id =  TheId }) where you need to pass a value for TheId    but you have to know what value you want to use there. Obviously it's not going to be random and will related to *something* (current model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IUrlHelper.Action` has [an overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UrlHelperExtensions_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_) which accepts an anonymous object containing route values. You need to call this overload and pass the necessary information to properly identity your action.

For example, suppose that your Id is stored in a `Guid` field on your Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   // other properties
}
```

The call to `Url.Action` might look like:

```
@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Photos", new { id = Model.Id });
```